# Is it good practice to throw exception from DAO layer to controller?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am writing one REST api. There might be two exceptions in my DAO layer namely `Exception_X` and `Exception_Y`. If I encountered a exception `Exception_X` in DAO layer, my controller should return status code `200`, if `Exception_Y` then `401` and if all goes well controller should return `201`.
Now what was I thinking that I will throw encountered exception as it is from DAO layer to controller via service layer and in `catch` block of controller I will return response.
Is it acceptable or there is some other standard way?

Comment: Yes, you can do like that. There no problem in your approach.

Comment: Yes you can and it would be better to create your own exceptions classes and construct those as per exceptions and throw them.

Comment: There is no standard way, and I see many Yes'es. But in my opinion: leave status codes where they are handled, at your controller. Something with seperation of concerns..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes that is quite an acceptable way. However, rather than using `try-catch`, I would suggest to implement Exception Handlers for your REST Controllers. That way, you won't have to clutter your REST methods.

Also, it would be better to create a model object in REST layer for Error messages - `ErrorResponse`, with appropriate information:

```
class ErrorResponse {
    int statusCode;
    String errorMessage;
}
```

And return it's object from the exception handlers. BTW, you can also map your exception class directly to a response using `@ResponseStatus` annotation:

```
@ResponseStatus(value=401, reason="message")
class Exception_Y extends RuntimeException {
}
```

Then you don't have to write exception handler for that exception.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be wrap any unchecked exceptions with a service layer for loose coupling, and clean abstraction. Keep your controller free from conditions and let Service layer take care of this pain.

Keeping security concern in mind if you exposing it externally wrap your exception with service oriented exception it also helps to achieve generic **layer specific exceptions** say PersistentException, ServiceException etc. keeping **good degree of decoupling** in mind.

For handling exception globally you can use spring inbuild ControllerAdvice annotation with JsonExceptionModel for formatted error response.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ExceptionHandler(SQLException.class)
    public Map<String, Object> handleSQLException(HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex) {
        //json response here
    }
}


public class JsonExceptionModel  {
    private int code;
    private String type;
    private String url;
    private String message;
    private String moreInfo;

// getters/setters here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go with Exception Resolver which is providing by spring.
Spring Framework provides HandlerExceptionResolver interface that we can implement to create global exception handler. We can also override it to create our own global handler with our application specific changes, such as logging of exception messages.

Here is the sample implementation of HandlerExceptionResolver,which will fullfill your need

```
public class RestResponseStatusExceptionResolver extends HandlerExceptionResolver {

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView doResolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
                                              Exception ex) {
        if (ex instanceof InvalidInputException) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
            return handleException(ex);
        } else if (ex instanceof ResourceNotFoundException) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
            return handleException(ex);
        }


//Adding error details to modelView object
modelAndView.addObject("errors", ErrorDetails);



// Custom error message details
public class ErrorDetails {
    private String code;
    private List<String> data;
}
```